# What are development and release key hashes effectively?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Android, and I am slowly getting used to it.
One of the main things I have to do is Facebook integration.
When I set up my Facebook app, I get this step from Facebook:

> To ensure the authenticity of the interactions between your app and Facebook, you need to supply us with the Android key hash for your development environment. If your app has already been published, you should add your release key hash too.

I did it, but what I do not understand (nor I find online) is:

- What *is* effectively this hash?
- What do they mean by "authenticity of the interactions between your app and Facebook"?
- What would be the possible security issues if this key wasn't provided? (or, why is Facebook asking for this?)

Answer (score 0):

When you make an app, you sign it with your keystore. That signature can be translated into a hash which is unique.

When your app connects to the facebook api, facebook will ask for this hash and verify whether or not it will allow you to connect.

By registering the hash with Facebook, **you're saying that you're responsible for the app**. By not providing this hash, Facebook will simply reject requests from your app until you do.

Comment: "you sign it with your keystore" -- what do you mean? What is the "Android key hash for your development environment"?

Comment: My first question should have read "What is the Android key hash for your development environment"?